# Invalidation of Eruv

Tags: sources-mekorot, shabbat, eruv-chatzerot

Could a Eruv become invalid if the majority of Jews are Mechallel Shabbos(desecrating the Shabbos)while using it e.g. driving a car in the boundaries of the Eruv, carrying and using mobile phones etc?

Comment: Why would you think these activities would invalidate an eruv?

Comment: That the people consider it unimportant and has no worth and therefore what it’s purpose.

Comment: Are they against the eruv or impartial to it,that can make a difference

Comment: Not against,  just that a piece of string can all of a sudden allow the person to do forbidden things now in a permitted manner. So to them it doesn’t really make difference whether there is an Eruv or not. At the end of the day if they want to be Mechallel Shabbos then they will be.

Comment: How are these Shabbat desecrators "using the eruv"? And does the fact the same people don't use public Sukkot make the Sukkot invalid? Why would the fact some Jews don't use something make the something any less functional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It depends. Did the Eruv organizers rent a portion of all residences within the Eruv boundaries?**

The Shulchan Aruch rules (cited below) that a Jew who desecrates Shabbos cannot *mevatel* (lit. cancel) owned home space to the Eruv users, but rather the Eruv users have to rent that Jew's property. If the Eruv organizers rented space in all homes inside the Eruv through the fire chief or another municipal authority figure, the actions of those who desecrate Shabbos should not make a difference. However, if the Eruv is only for Jewish homes, for example, an entirely Jewish courtyard or an entirely Jewish apartment building, and no renting of property was done, then the public Shabbos desecration would disqualify the Eruv.

It should be noted that this is not a question of the Eruv boundaries, walls, or strings being disqualified, but rather the partnership between Eruv users (usually through a communal two matzos) that gives significance to the Eruv walls and strings.

---

כ' שו"ע (או"ח שפה:ג) ישראל מומר לעבודת אלילים או לחלל שבתות בפרהסיא אפי' אינו מחללו אלא באיסור דרבנן הרי הוא כעכו"ם ואם אינו מחלל אלא בצינעה אפי' מחללו באיסור דאורייתא הרי הוא כישראל ומבטל רשות